# jQuery binding current element item to the whole window

Tags: jquery

I am creating a chat client for a social network I'm building as a fun sort of learning project.

I have a chat window item which gets appended to my document each time a user is selected from the friends list.

I want to bind two elements in my chat window to perform different actions, how do I go about this? currently I am doing the following:

```
// Collapse the current chat window
$('body').on('click', '.title', function(){
    $(this).animate({'margin-top' : '-100px'}, 100);
});

// Close the current chat window
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){ 
           // get the current chat window
   var window = $(this).getElementById('#chatWindow');
   window.remove();
});
```

I assume I am doing something wrong with the reference I am passing for 'this', I am fairly novice with javascript so forgive me if my question is too simplistic.

Thanks for your time.

NOTE - Chat window code

```
<div id="chatWindow" class="chat1">
    <div class="title"><span><div id="online"></div>Alex Sims</span><a class="close" href="#">X</a></div>
    <div class="message"><p class="msg1">Hey, are you still stuck?</p></div>
    <div class="text"><input type="text" placeholder="Message..."></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the event handler attachment `on()` is `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )`, so `this` refers to the `selector` passed. See [api.jquery.com/on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It's better to attach events on `document`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.title', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-top': '-100px'
    }, 100);
}).on('click', '.close', function (e) {
    //this refers to '.close'
    //use `closest()` to travel up the DOM tree until it finds '#chatWindow'
    $(this).closest('#chatWindow').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you wrap your all `chatWindow`s in a div like `chat-window-wrapper`.

Apply it as

```
<div id="chat-window-wrapper" class="chat1">
  <div id="chatWindow" class="chat1">
      <div class="title"><span><div id="online"></div>Alex Sims</span><a class="close" href="#">X</a></div>
      <div class="message"><p class="msg1">Hey, are you still stuck?</p></div>
      <div class="text"><input type="text" placeholder="Message..."></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Do not apply the events on the Body. But apply them on that `chat-window-wrapper`. One thing I would mention that `chat-window-wrapper` must stay on the page even if there is no `chatWindow` in it.

```
// Collapse the current chat window
$('chat-window-wrapper').on('click', '.title', function(){
    $(this).animate({'margin-top' : '-100px'}, 100);
    // Or i guess you want to -100PX the whole chat window. for that use the following line
    // $(this).closest('#chatWindow').animate({'margin-top' : '-100px'}, 100);
})
// Close the current chat window
.on('click', '.close', function(){ 
           // get the current chat window
   var window = $(this).closest('#chatWindow').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Talha, I have reworked my app structure :)